# How can I run a Chrome extension in NW.js?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

This question is pretty short and self explanatory. I'm wondering how I can run my Chrome extension in NW.js.

I know you can run an app in NW.js and I think you can run extensions as well?

I can't find much on the topic. Back in 2013 the way to do it seemed to be:

```
nw [path to manifest.json] --load-extension
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: It seems like perhaps my extension runs, but it runs from a hotkey combination when I run it in Chrome.

How do I emulate that functionality in NW.js? (assuming it is really running properly in the background)

Comment: Why? Extensions are meant to affect browser behavior.

Comment: Because my extension is built to behave much more like an app like Join from joaoapps, but I knew apps were going to be discontinued so I began my work this way. Now I'm wondering if Electron or NW.js would have been a better way to approach the issue, but I have a good deal of code down.

Comment: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Chrome%20Extension%20APIs/

Comment: Thank you, but that has no useful information for resolving my issue.

Comment: Just a guess, try http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Shortcut/

Comment: @Slbox did you install the extension properly finally?

Comment: @RezaAmya, nope. Sorry. I eventually just ported my work by hand to Electron.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

First off, download the extension you want. For this example I'll be using [this debugging tool](https://github.com/spite/ShaderEditorExtension), which adds an additional tab in the dev tools window.

- Inside your NW.js `package.json` file, ensure you have an entry called `chromium-args`.
- Ensure its value contains `--enable-extensions --load-extension=relative_path_to_extension_manifest.`

My `package.json` looks like this:

[image]

After restarting the application, the extension shows up as expected:

[image]

Something I'll add is that the full Chrome API might not be available to you. I couldn't find info about what NW.js supports, but Electron definitely [does not support the entire API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/extensions#supported-extensions-apis), so this might have similar restrictions.

I also noticed you mention in the comments that you need to assign a hotkey of sorts. I'd need to know what you were trying to do, but essentially you have the option of either using a browser mechanism such as [`addEventListener('keydown', myHandler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or using the [NW.js API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744592/nw-js-how-to-make-f11-hot-key-to-switch-between-full-screen-window-and-standard) depending on your exact needs.